# Why is the difference between two dates returning one extra day?

Tags: java

I have the following `Instant` object

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2018-11-29T00:00:00.00Z");
verify(instant, 5);
```

And the date today is Nov 24, 2018. I want to write a method that verifies that the `instant` is 5 days from today. Here is the method:

```
public void verify(Instant instant, int offsetInDays)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.from(localDateTime);
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    assertEquals(offsetInDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, endDate));
}
```

It should assert that 5 is equal to 5, but `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, endDate)` is returning 6 days. Why is there an extra day in the comparison? I'm unable to figure out how to do an accurate comparison.

Comment: LocalDate.now() is not in UTC time zone, hence the extra day...

Comment: @moilejter I changed it to LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) and it still returns 6 days

Comment: Print out the two date values, converted to the same time zone, so you can see what it's comparing?

Comment: Actually @moilejter you were right.. thanks for pointing that out. I ran the test sometime yesterday morning and it worked. But tonight it didnt because UTC time actually makes it Nov 30 1am instead of Nov 29 7pm. adding ZoneOffset.UTC did in fact fix it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you're exposing some conversions that you aren't aware of, by forcing `UTC` in the first line of `verify()`, and then converting it to `LocalDate`. This works regardless of the time zones involved on my machine.

```
public void verify(Instant instant, int offsetInDays)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalDateTime endDate = localDateTime.plusDays(offsetInDays);
    assertEquals(offsetInDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(localDateTime, endDate));
}
```